Combining Cyrillic and Latin text in gb4e interlinear gloss
I want to combine Cyrillic and Latin text in gb4e's interlinear gloss. But I always retrieved an error.
This is my tex document:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}

\ex
\gll Путин опроверг дискриминацию геев в России \\
putin oproverg diskriminatsiju gejev v rossii \\
putin membantah-V-LAMP-PERF diskriminasi-AKU gay-GEN di rusia-PREP \\
\trans Putin membantah adanya diskriminasi terhadap kelompok gay di Rusia

\end{exe}

\end{document}

And it retrieved me this error:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./gloss.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/gb4e/gb4e.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/gb4e/cgloss4e.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./gloss.aux)

./gloss.tex:11: LaTeX Error: Unicode character П (U+041F)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.11 ...oproverg dis
./gloss.tex:11: LaTeX Error: Unicode character у (U+0443)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.11 ...oproverg diskriminatsiju gejev v rossii \\
                                                  
? kriminatsiju gejev v rossii \\
                                                  
? 

Is there any way to improve my document?
I am using the TeXShop in Mac.

You need to load Russian babel. However, since \gll wants to split the input at spaces, you can't do \foreignlanguage{russian}{<sentence>}, but treat separately every word.
Using a short command is better, in my opinion.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[russian,indonesian]{babel}

\newcommand{\?}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}

\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}

\ex
\gll \?{Путин} \?{опроверг} \?{дискриминацию} \?{геев} \?{в} \?{России} \\
putin oproverg diskriminatsiju gejev v rossii \\
putin membantah-V-LAMP-PERF diskriminasi-AKU gay-GEN di rusia-PREP \\
\trans Putin membantah adanya diskriminasi terhadap kelompok gay di Rusia

\end{exe}

\end{document}



Thank you, it works!

+1: Very cool command name (?)

@Dr.ManuelKuehner Good for the particular situation, not generally.


A custom macro, \glinlines{}, can apply formatting to the entire line, keeping spaces as dividers.
MWE


\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[russian,indonesian]{babel}
 
%\newcommand{\?}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}

\usepackage{xcolor,luacolor,lua-ul}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}
\input{in-glinlines2.tex}
\setmainlanguage{indonesian}
\setotherlanguage{russian}
\usepackage{tikz} % before gb4e
\usepackage{gb4e}


\begin{document}

\glsetfirstlineformat{\selectlanguage{russian}\large}
\glsetsecondlineformat{\sffamily\color{brown}}
\mfssetposformat{\scshape \bfseries\sffamily}

 before::

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}

\ex
\glinlines{%
    Путин опроверг дискриминацию геев в России:ldots
*/ putin oproverg diskriminatsiju gejev v rossii\ldots
*/ putin membantah.V.Lamp.Perf diskriminasi.Aku gay.Gen di rusia.Prep\ldots
glt \itshape ’Putin membantah adanya diskriminasi terhadap kelompok gay di Rusia'
}
\end{exe}

::after

\end{document}


Usage: Inside a linguistic example, instead of one command for each line, one macro covers all line types: interlinear lines are delimited by a character string not elsewhere used (default */), and free-form text lines are delimited by another character string also not elsewhere used (default glt).
The data structure is: one or more interlinear lines, each followed by zero or more free-form text lines.
A "traditional" linguistic example, if it can be called that, is structured as: one, two, or three interlinear lines with the last interlinear line being followed by zero or one free-form text line.
If the delimiters are present in the text, different ones (e.g., xx) can be set per example via an option.
The macro can also be used wherever normal text is expected, such as a footnote, inline text, etc.
How it works: Words are boxed, then the word boxes are stacked into wordstacks whose widths are set to the width of the widest wordbox in the stack, plus a little bit extra for readability. Expl3 is used for this.
Spaces are used as delimiters. All interlinear lines must have the same number of spaces, for the words to line up. To treat   two or more as a unit, brace them {}.
Words can be individually formatted (or code inserted) using a basic markdown affixed to the word (to preserve the spaces), and then regexed back to Latex commands. For example, text:command becomes text\command. See the reference manual for many more examples.
Lines can be formatted to increase legibilty. See the MWE for some examples.
Wordstacks can also be formatted, for highlighting a special feature for example.
Other capabilities are ruby text, selecting the desired tone mark from the xpinyin.def database, and producing a parts-of-speech glossary.

Hooking into the text flow: adding differently-formatted punctuation.

Hooking into the text flow: adding tikzmark anchor points to do an overlay.

Defining a custom line separator.

Wordstacks made visible.

Highlighting a wordstack.



Termux: "micro" editor screens on Android tablet.
Supporting code for the macro is too big to fit into this answer. A "full" TexLive install is assumed. r past any font messages (or edit the fontnames) as a workaround until I/you make them conditional or otherwise de-hardcode them. ((There should be a function for this, ideally. Hmmmm...))
Copy in-glinlines2.tex and in-glossing.tex from https://github.com/texcicada/expl3
Reference PDF: https://github.com/texcicada/expl3/blob/main/glinlines-demo2.pdf

Answers should be as self-explanatory and self-contained as possible. It would therefore certainly be helpful if you would not only announce the minimal working example, but actually show how the problem from the question can be solved with the help of the linked pages.

Welcome! The code looks good (untested), but why include pictures of code, too? Images of code really aren't useful: they can't be copied easily and they are inaccessible to screen reading software. Perhaps a picture of the output could be added instead?

@cfr Apologies. I was not expecting anyone to be so quick over the weekend. I was still working how to get information out of an Android app pocket universe bubble (not quick or simple) combined with prioritising the information flow in case something happened (long story).

@cfr A picture of the output is/now at the top.
